# Develop PostgreSQL on Mavericks (OS X 10.9)

Tags: c, macos, postgresql, debugging, gdb

I'm try to debug PostgreSQL in Eclipse / Netbeans / QtCreator on Mavericks (OS X 10.9).

I have tried various compilers (GCC 4.2, CLang) in the various IDEs, different debuggers (GDB, LLDB), but I haven't found a configuration that works - especially in the sense that I can debug the code properly.

I'm currently trying with GCC 4.2 and GDB. I have installed GCC via homebrew and also certified gdb. I can compile the PostgreSQL source code and run it. However, each time I try to attach the debugger to the running threads, I always (independent of IDE) the following error:

```
Mach error at "darwin-at.c:726" in function "void darwin_resume_thread(struct inferior *, darwin_thread_t *, int, int)": (os/kern) failure (0x5).
```

Do you have any ideas what this means? Or do you have maybe a clue how I can get PostgreSQL to compile, debug and run on OS X 10.9?

Answer (score 1):

Use the compiler and debugger from XCode, not one installed from Macports / Homebrew / whatever. Build with `llvm` and debug with `lldb`.

You might need to install XCode 5 for this to work on your new OS X.

Apple tends to rather freely break kernel interfaces, etc, when they update the OS, and rarely document these changes for 3rd parties. So it sometimes takes time for 3rd party tools to catch up and work on the latest OS X. In this case it seems reasonably likely that they've messed with the debug interfaces used by `gdb`.

If you still have issues when using the XCode 5 toolchain, post about that with specifics. The current question is a little bit of everything, so it's hard to pin down details.

Given that this is a Mach error (i.e. the kernel is complaining) it's also possible you've got a 3rd party driver or utility that's causing issues with a hook. Check what kernel extensions you've got installed.

Comment: Thanks a lot, that was a very good hint and brought me much further. But still I have some problems with debugging. I use QT Creator because it's the only IDE (experimentally) supporting LLVM and LLDB. When I try to attach to a running application, LLDB gives me an "error: unable to find executable for '/Applications/postgres: navige postgres 127.0.0.1(50996) idle" and "EXCEPTION CAUGHT: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'GetSelectedThread'". It seems that it cannot find postgres since it checks for it in /Applications and I have not located it there. But how to change that path?

Comment: @navige Why not use XCode? You're on a Mac, you get to use use Apple tools, and sometimes don't get much choice. It's an IDE. It has a debugger. Anyway, please *post a new question* for a new problem.